# TSQL for crystal report

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

The sql below works for a total number. ie customer spends 90,000 they get discount of .01 But
if they spend 150,000 in q1 the first 100,000 should be discount of .01, the next should 50,000 should be at .02
but when Q2 starts the number should be a yearly one. IE if in Q1 they spent 100000 and in q2 100,000 then they are at the 200,000 mark from then on

```
 Select Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
 Case is <= 100000: 0.01*Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
 case   100001 to  200000: 0.020*Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
 default: 0.030*Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
```

I was able to come up wiith this for Q1 but dont know what to do for the other 3

```
  Select Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
  Case is <= 100000: 0.01*Sum ({@fBillingQ1})
  case   100001 to  200000: (0.01*Sum ({@fBillingQ1}))+(0.020*Sum ({@fBillingQ1} - 100000))
  default: ((0.01*Sum ({@fBillingQ1}))+(0.020*Sum ({@fBillingQ1} - 100000))+(0.030*Sum ({@fBillingQ1}-      200000))
```

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post additional detail about te table structure of your SQL source? Are Q1-Q4 totals all in different fields, or is there a Billing Amount field with another field that provides quarter/time?

Comment: The sales are all in the same fields, the report sums the sales fields and is then filtered to give a quarterly amount.